# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, file-permissions

I have built this code to specifically identify a load of .XML files and to extract co-ordinates from those files. Here is my code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)

workspace = "D:/J040083"
gp.workspace = workspace

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(workspace): # returms root, dirs, and files
    for filename in filenames:
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(filename) # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
        filename_zero = filename_split[0]
        extension = str.upper(filename_split[1])

        try:
            first_2_letters = str.upper(filename_zero[0] + filename_zero[1])
        except:
            first_2_letters = "XX"

        if first_2_letters == "LI" and extension == ".XML":
            tree = ET.parse(workspace)
            print tree.find('//{http://www.opengis.net/gml}lowerCorner').text
            print tree.find('//{http://www.opengis.net/gml}upperCorner').text
```

I am having trouble with an error:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    D:\J040083\TXT_EXTRACTION.py    32      
    parse   C:\Python25\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py    862     
    parse   C:\Python25\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py    579     
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/J040083'
```

I definitely do have access to this folder! I have also tried making new, empty folders and putting just one .xml file in there but i get the same error! Does anyone have any idea what has gone wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us what line 32 contains in the TXT_EXTRACTION.PY script? The text box in the question doesn't have that many lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change the line

```
tree = ET.parse(workspace)
```

to

```
tree = ET.parse(filename)
```

because workspace is a directory and the parse method takes a filename.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to write the file path with `\` instead of `/`:

```
workspace = "D:\\J040083"
```

Or, without backslash escaping as a raw string:

```
workspace = r"D:\J040083"
```

Comment: I have tried every combinations of \\ or / or even // (just clutching at straws here!)

Comment: Use the value of os.filesep to build that path.